# Get alerts for upload activity with libtorrent (rasterbar)

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent

I am trying to get alerts for the data that I'm sending peers.  My code works great for incoming blocks by looking for libtorrent.block_finished_alert but I want to know when and what I am sending to peers.  I can't find an alert that will give me the equivalent for outbound transfers.  I need to know the file and offset (the peer request).

Is there an alert for outbound block requests?

I'm using the python bindings but C++ code is fine too.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you have to alerts is probably `stats_alert`. It will tell you the number of payload bytes uploaded. It won't give the you granularity of a full block being sent though.

If you'd like to add an alert, have a look at `bt_peer_connection::write_piece`.

patches are welcome!